# Pass json inside a file to Python click

Tags: python, json, click, command-line-interface

I'm using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) to build a CLI tool. I need my code to open a file in a specified directory (this is what is passed as a command line argument) and parse the json inside that file. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you see https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/quickstart/#basic-concepts-creating-a-command

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) for more information, but to give you a warm start:

```py
import json

import click


@click.command()
@click.argument("json_file", type=click.File("rb"))
def cli(json_file):
    # click already handles opening up the file
    # and passes `input_path` as a stream of bytes
    # since we specified `"rb"`
    _json_file = json.load(json_file)
    print(_json_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```